# C++ not compiling because its say the file doesn't exist but it is in the same directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, header-files

in a folder I got the following files:

book.h, book.cpp , card.h, card.cpp

these are the content of the book.h

```
class book {

public:
        string title;
        string author;
        string get_title();
        string get_author();

}

book::book(string title, string author){
   title = title;
   author = author;
}
```

this is my book.cpp:

```
#include <book.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string book::get_title(){

  return title;
}

string book::get_author(){
 return author;
}

int main(){

cout << ¨it works! \n¨ 
}
```

I I try to compile using g++ -c book.cpp, I keep getting an error message saying:

book.cpp:1:18: fatal error: book.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: User includes should be in `""` not `<>`.

Comment: Not the answer but... your book.h looks wrong anyway. You need to use std::string and include the <string> in header as well.

Comment: There are some other problems with this code. `book.h` should `#include <string>`, and have `std::string`. throughout instead of `string`. Don't do `using namespace std` ever, it's a bad idea. `title = title;` doesn't do what you think it does. Having public data members defeats the purpose of accessors.

Comment: Why did you spammed the C tag for an obvious C++ question ?

Comment: Look i dont know better ok? I am new to this sorry for the confusion

Comment: Don't name your constructor variables the same as your class variables unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Another possibility is that the file isn't actually named `"book.h"` but `"Book.h"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
#include <book.h>
```

and

```
#include "book.h"
```

is that the first one looks for the file `book.h` in INCLUDE path only. The latter looks for the file first in the directory where the source file is and if it was not found then it looks for it in INCLUDE path.
So you can resolve your issue either by replacing angle brackets with quotes, or by adding your directory to INCLUDE. You can do it by compiling like this

```
g++ -I . -c book.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

`#include` statements use `<>` brackets when the included file is part of your "Include" path, typically (though not exclusively) when the file is coming from a library, or the C++ Standard Library.

`""` is used instead when the file is local to the project and local to the source code.

If you mix them up, you're going to have a bad time.